# Different APK for same source code - Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-ndk, java-native-interface

The attached image shows the APK(unzipped) generated from the same project in two different machines.

[image: APK content of same source from different machines]

As you can see, the APK contents are different in both the scenario.In the second APK edu, lib,or,Android.mk, classes.dex, LICENSE.txt, pocketsphinx.i, pocketsphinx_wrap.c are not there.I do not understand why this difference in APK content with same code in different machines. Obviously, the second APK does not give me the proper output and while trying to launch, crashes with the following log:

```
01-01 00:17:13.092: DEBUG/dalvikvm(3458): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-01 00:17:13.100: INFO/ActivityManager(2302): Start proc or.exp.voicereco for activity or.exp.voicereco/.CameraMain: pid=3458 uid=10070 gids={1015}
01-01 00:17:13.124: INFO/dalvikvm(2302): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no .odex file in the same directory
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302): IOException reading apk: /system/app/PocketSphinxDemo.apk
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302): java.io.IOException: /system/app/PocketSphinxDemo.apk
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.isDexOptNeeded(Native Method)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.performDexOptLI(PackageManagerService.java:3172)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.performDexOpt(PackageManagerService.java:3157)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.ensurePackageDexOpt(ActivityManagerService.java:1869)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3876)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:4013)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:351)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1616)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
01-01 00:17:13.124: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-01 00:17:13.131: INFO/dalvikvm(2302): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no .odex file in the same directory
01-01 00:17:13.131: INFO/ActivityManager(2302): app/or.exp.voicereco[RESUMED] app.idle/false ...realStartActivityLocked
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302): IOException reading apk: /system/app/PocketSphinxDemo.apk
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302): java.io.IOException: /system/app/PocketSphinxDemo.apk
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at dalvik.system.DexFile.isDexOptNeeded(Native Method)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.performDexOptLI(PackageManagerService.java:3172)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.performDexOpt(PackageManagerService.java:3157)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.ensurePackageDexOpt(ActivityManagerService.java:1869)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:601)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3925)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:4013)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:351)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1616)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
01-01 00:17:13.131: WARN/PackageManager(2302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-01 00:17:13.147: INFO/dalvikvm(3458): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
01-01 00:17:13.155: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(3458): Shutting down VM
01-01 00:17:13.155: WARN/dalvikvm(3458): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b021f8)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{or.exp.voicereco/    or.exp.voicereco.CameraMain}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: or.exp.voicereco.CameraMain
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1989)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1149)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4368)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: or.exp.voicereco.CameraMain
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1873)
01-01 00:17:13.155: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3458):     ... 11 more
01-01 00:17:13.155: WARN/ActivityManager(2302):   Force finishing activity or.exp.voicereco/.CameraMain
```

Can someone please let me know why I get proper output when I compile and run the app from one machine and not in the other. While for all other applications, the APK generated is perfect in the second machine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Anees

PS: This is an ndk based application.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with your build scripts / build environment.

Comment: I am just copying the JNI folder from another working application in both these machines. In first machine I build this from eclipse and in second machine I build it along with android source. Is there anything obvious that you see which might cause this issue?

Comment: Show the contents of Android.mk. If it is not setup properly building using the Android build system will not create a valid APK. Most likely it is only building your native code. BTW, you don't need to include your code (*.c and *.i files) in your APK. Might be a good idea to move those to a separate directory, along with the makefile. The convention is to use `jni/` under the app project.

Comment: I do not have an Android.mk in jni/ unlike other ndk based applications. As I told, I have copied the JNI directory from a working application to the application I made. When I load this application in eclipse, it works perfect, with and without Android.mk in /jni. Do you really think, I should have an Android.mk inside jni/ ?